# Cardinality of maps from {0,1} to R as binary numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I understand why the cardinality of maps from R(the real) to {0,1} would be 2^R. I heard about how the maps from {0,1} to R can be thought of as binary numbers(which are uncountable), but I can not visualize it. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I do not recommend visualizing maps from $\{0,1\}\to\Bbb R$ as binary numbers.  This is very simply going to be the set $\{\{(0,a),(1,b)\}~:~a,b\in\Bbb R\}=\{f(x)=\begin{cases}a&\text{if }x=0\\b&\text{if }x=1\end{cases}~:~a,b\in\Bbb R\}$.  In particular it has the function $f(x)=1$ and the function $f(x)=2$ and the function $f(x)=\sqrt{2}$ and the function $f(x)=3133742$ and the function $f(x)=y$ for any desired $y\in \Bbb R$

Comment: Maps $\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$ can be thought of as binary real numbers in $[0,1]$ though there is a slight issue over dyadic fractions

Answer (score 0):

Basically because the maps from $\{0,1\}$ to $\Bbb R$ can be thought of as pairs in $\Bbb R^2$ and the plane has the same size as $\Bbb R$.